# Is there anyway to easily add rss feeds to outlook?

Tags: html, xml, django, rss, cross-browser

I have written code that genereates several thousand rss feeds and displays them as links (using django if it matters) in a browser page. The issue I have is that only firefox seems to be able to natively understand that a rss xml file is an rss feed and asks if you want to add it to a program like outlook. both IE and Chrome simply display the xml code. Without forcing everyone who uses IE or Chrome to install a plugin to handle rss feeds, is there some way i can change my web page code so that clicking the rss link will attempt to open that feed in a browser? I appreciate any and all responses.

Comment: "links" as in "hypertext links" as in "<a href='blahblah.rss'>", or "links" as in "page metadata" as in "<link rel='alternate' type='application/rss+xml' href='blahblah.rss'>"?  Most modern browsers understand the latter, and put a small RSS icon near the address bar to allow you to subscribe.  If the former, it's probably a matter of what content type your server is serving the XML with.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the Q correctly, your XML is not displaying clickable links.

This is the default behavior.

To make IE and Chrome activate your links, you need to transform your XML with XSL.

This is a decent reference on transforming your entire XML file: http://www.xefteri.com/articles/show.cfm?id=24

(Depending on the current set up, thousands of changes may be out of the question, but this gives you an idea on how it could be done.)

Comment: While helpful with a different part of my project the problem I have is that I want to be able to have the rss feeds import into a rss reader like google reader or outlook (like it works in Firefox) but it instead displays the xml code. while an xsl translation will allow me to format the feed preview in an xml reader, It does not ofer the option of importing it into a reader